# Centering and scaling each subject individually - mixed effect models

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, residuals, assumptions

I have a repeated measures design with two factors (A,B). For each subject, variable C is measured 7 to 10 times in each combination of A and B.

My first approach was to scale and center each variable and to calculate (more or less) this model in R:

```
  model <- lmer(C~A*B+(1+A*B|Subject), data)
```

However the `qqplot` showed some deviations especially for the (-)4th quantiles

[image: qqplot]

So tried some options, and what I found was, that when I scaled and centered C for each subject individually before modeling, the `qqplot` fitted much better:

[image]

Which (in my opinion) shows me, that the model doesn't fit the subjects individual means and SDs well.

So, I have two questions:

1. Is my second approach, statistically valid?
2. Can I somehow model the individual scaling in my model, so I do not have to scale each subject first?

Note, both versions show me quite similar results when I ignore the `qqplot` (in regards to effect sizes, and significance; for sure there is no need of an intercept in the second model anymore).